# Discrete series representation of $SO(2,1)$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, unitarity

Since $so(2,1)$ is a noncompact Lie algebra, its unitary representations are all infinite-dimensional. Now, I have seen that the unitary representations of $so(2,1)$ can be divided into three categories:

1. Discrete series - with a lowest or highest state satisfying $J_{\pm}|j,m\rangle = 0$, where $C|j,m\rangle = -j(j+1) |j,m\rangle$ ($C$ is the Casimir operator) and $J_3|j,m\rangle = m|j,m\rangle$. Also $J_\pm = J_1 \pm iJ_2$.
2. Principal series.
3. Complementary series.

For principal and complementary series, there is no lower or upper bound for the $m$ values. Now, I have seen in most books and literature that for the discrete series, $j$ only takes integer or half-integer values rather than continuum values which gives the name discrete series. However, I cannot find any reason why should $j,m$ only can have integer or half-integer values if there is a lower bound on the $m$ values.

In other words, starting with the assumption that there exists a lower or upper bound of the value $m$, how can we conclude that $j$ has to be discrete?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: why lower *or* upper? there is both lower *and* upper bounds on the value $m$, as from the equality $C=J_1^2+J_2^2+J_3^2$ it is restricted between $j(j+1)$ and $-j(j+1)$ since $||C|| \geq ||J_3^2||$, no?

Comment: @yyy No, there will be only upper or lower bound because the Casimir here is $C=J_1^2+J_2^2-J_3^2$. What you wrote is correct for $so(3)$ algebra but not in this case.

Comment: @Qmechanic link to mathematics stack exchange question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4267052/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.

Comment: @abhijit975 oh I misread the question, sorry. thank you for clarifying